# Roll the sum of count for weekends into Monday's count

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am pulling shipment counts for each day of the week. Since the operation is automated over the weekend I need to roll the count of those shipments into Monday's count.

I started with the simple query:

```
SELECT date(im.Import_date_time) AS 'Date',
    COUNT(im.Tracking_Number) AS 'Imports'
 FROM invoice_master im
    WHERE im.Import_date_time >= '2019-01-07'
 GROUP BY date(im.Import_date_time)
```

I tried to add:

```
 CASE
   WHEN weekday(*) IN (5,6,0) THEN SUM(*)
   ELSE COUNT(*)
 END 
 AS 'Shipments'
```

I then tried COUNT in the WHEN clause. None of these worked- syntax errors all the way.

I also tried adding a subquery, which I don't have the query for anymore, and it just gave me the same results as the initial query.

Using the subquery and case I had together gets me the same result as the initial query.

My basic query gets the obvious results:

Date    Import

1/7/2019    5432

1/8/2019    18434

1/9/2019    4603

1/10/2019   1916

1/11/2019   2287

*1/12/2019    90*

1/13/2019   3091

1/14/2019   6915

I need:

Date    Import

1/7/2019    5432

1/8/2019    18434

1/9/2019    4603

1/10/2019   1916

1/11/2019   2287

**1/14/2019    10096**

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression to add an offset, when necessary:

```
SELECT (case when dayofweek(im.Import_date_time) in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
             then date(im.Import_date_time)
             when dayofweek(im.Import_date_time) = 1
             then date(im.Import_date_time) + interval 1 day
             when dayofweek(im.Import_date_time) = 7
             then date(im.Import_date_time) + interval 2 day
        end) as dte
       COUNT(*) AS Imports
FROM invoice_master im
WHERE im.Import_date_time >= '2019-01-07'
GROUP BY dte;
```